# which java version need to be uninstall

Tags: java, eclipse

I already researched on how to install Eclipse Luna. One of the things to consider before installing Eclipse is to choose the JDK (planning to use JDK 8). It said that it is recommend that if I have an older version of Java, I need to uninstall it. But here's the problem: I don't know which I should uninstall. Here is the list of installed versions in my control panel (Windows 7 64bit):

1. Java 7
2. Java(TM) 6 Update 45
3. Java(TM) SE development kit 6 (i think this one but what's with (TM)?)

Comment: you dont really need to uninstall anything, all what you need is to  set in your luna path your java 7 jdk

Comment: Unless you have some application that specifically demands an older version (which is rare and should be avoided), the easier way is touninstall all of them. Note that usually there is no issue with multiple versions being installed as long as you ensure eclipse is using the right one.

Comment: thank you. this really help me. yes i do have some application that use older version of java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run `java -version` at the command line to see which one is in your PATH. This is the one that will run the Eclipse workspace.

Unless you have clear requirements to use older Java versions, I would recommend to uninstall all of them. And just have the latest JRE or better JDK installed.

In my case, I have a JRE to run the Eclipse workspace that is maintained by the Admin people and a private JDK (to provide additional tools, such as `javadoc`) to support the software development. You can have several Java versions installed (without having them in the PATH environment listed). You can point to them in the workspace settings or in specific Eclipse projects, e.g., to use a Java 6 for a certain project.

Comment: thanks. i just tried runnning java -version . I will install JDK 8 just for eclipse

Comment: This isn't good advice. Eclipse provides a way to specify the exact JVM to use, via eclipse.ini

Comment: True that. Be careful with deleting things unless you know who installed it and which program relies on it. However, considering the many security issues with Java, it is definitely wise to remove outdated versions unless there is a urgent need and knowing that it doesn't expose your system.

Answer (score 1):

It is strongly recommended to specify what JVM (preferably a JDK) Eclipse should run in, via the [eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) file. That way you can have any number of JDKs and/or JREs without problem. In fact, Eclipse also allows you to have multiple Java versions on your machine and each project in Eclipse can dictate exactly which one it uses. You can easily mix-and-match projects that use different Java versions, and they're all *independent* of the JVM that Eclipse itself is running in.

Answer (score 0):

I think Eclipse Luna needs Java 7.
A Java 7 JRE/JDK is required for most of the Luna package downloads based on Eclipse 4.4.

In my opinion you can uninstall Java(TM) 6 Update 45 & Java(TM) SE development kit 6